# linking numbers outside a pivot table to pivot table totals

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a summary table of budget to actual sales and I inserted a pivot table at the bottom that will automatically update to show the details of the summary. I want my summary table actuals to be linked to the monthly totals in my pivot table, but as my pivot table is refreshed with new data the cell numbers change. How can I makes sure the the pivot table totals are always linked/reflected in my summary table?

Comment: What does this have to do with OS X? Which software? Excel?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without knowing more about your data and summary table. For example, does the pivot table have detail numbers with embedded totals? (I'm think you don't have enough rep to upload a screenshot of what you want, which would be helpful to see.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to use the getpivotdata function? My pivot table does not automatically use that function so if I want a cell outside of the pivot table to equal a sum inside the pivot table, it will stay on that cell rather than stay on the sum when the pivot table expands with more data. I just not sure how to use that function.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with it myself. Here's a [**reference**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/getpivotdata-HP005209107.aspx) to Microsoft documentation on the function. Another way to go would be with a VLOOKUP on the pivot table.